# Aviation ebook for beginners?

Tags: website

I'm new to aviation but I am very passionate about it. I'm just 14 years old, so please help me in finding a good e-book about aviation for free.

I don't know how to search with Google about it.

Comment: "A book about aviation" is an entirely too broad topic.  If you have a specific interest within aviation that you are looking for a book about, that would be a better question.  As worded, thousands of books could be suggested to you and none of them may be helpful to you nor people that show up from google.  With that said, welcome to Aviation.SE!  You can take a look at the help center: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help to get a better idea of what type of questions are appropriate for this site.  Welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Although this is a question based on opinion, it might perhaps have some value as a community wiki so I've marked this 'answer' as such. I also borrowed one of Manfred's links. Feel free to append stuff to the list.

- In terms of free download, I can definitely recommend the [FAA Airplane Flying Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/) which can be found on the FAA web site. There are also a number of other handbooks there which are great reads. To be honest, I find this the best introductory book I know, free or otherwise.
- If you're out for a good reference book, something like Anderson's *Introduction to Flight* will be good, but bear in mind this is hardly an easy read but does cover virtually everything you will need to know. An [older edition](http://ae.sharif.edu/~iae/Download/Introduction%20to%20flight.pdf) seems to be available online.

Comment: In terms of the FAA stuff I would go even further: [The FAA has a pretty comprehensive series of handbooks on pretty much every aviation topic you can think of](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/), all available as PDFs.

Comment: @voretaq7 that's what I was referring to by "a number of other handbooks", but feel free to update the post and append the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aviation is a pretty complicated topic and can get very overwhelming very quickly, so it's not easy to locate something specifically.

eBooks however are not too easy to find, since you'll get the full load of manuals and regulatory documents in the search. You might find something (including the ordinary print books below) by searching for `book_name filetype:pdf` in google.

- If you're out for a good reference book, something like Anderson's *Introduction to Flight* will be good, but bear in mind this is hardly an easy read but does cover virtually everything you will need to know. An [older edition](http://ae.sharif.edu/~iae/Download/Introduction%20to%20flight.pdf) seems to be available online.
- There are plenty of books on flight simulation, which is often a great place to start. A fantastic one I picked up with lots of facts and stuff was *Flight Simulator X for Pilots* written by Van West and Lane-Cummings. This covers everything from navigations, maps and handling the aircraft. There are a lot of similar stuff on websites and youtube as well.
- There are plenty of websites on model aircraft building and drones. Less theory and more practise, but anyway interesting and educational.
- There are plenty of pilot blogs around, where you can read lots of good stuff.

I could also suggest that you join the edX **free online course given by Delft University of Technology in [Aeronautical Engineering](https://www.edx.org/course/delftx/delftx-ae1110x-introduction-aeronautical-1201)**. You get a certificate at the end as well if I'm not wrong, and it should give you a decent introduction if you're able to keep up with it :) Top 20 technical university and the largest faculty in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Sporty's ground school course is pretty helpful, you can get it for free if you can get yourself on an EAA Young Eagles flight.

**I am not sure about ebooks, but you can find copies of these books on eBay or Amazon.**

- As the Pro Flies (John R. Hoyt)
- Stick and Rudder (Wolfgang Langewiesche)

**General interesting aviation books**

- Janes All the World's Aircraft
- Janes Aircraft Recognition Guide
- A Field Guide to Airplanes, Third Edition (M. R. Montgomery)